# mysqldump: MySql backup user is not able to connect using password

Tags: mysql, backup

I have created a mysql user using following command:

```
CREATE USER 'backupuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

I have given him permissions using following command:

```
GRANT EVENT, LOCK TABLES, SELECT, SHOW DATABASES, RELOAD, REPLICATION CLIENT ON *.* TO 'backupuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

But when I try to do database dump using following command it does not work:

```
sudo mysqldump -ubackupuser -ppassword --all-databases > all_db_backup.sql
```

It says: `mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'backupuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to connect`

But if I try to connect without using password then it asks for password and then it works.

I am creating  a backup script so I have to pass the password in command. Can you please help how to make my backupuser to connect using mysql dump?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your password contain any characters that are special to the shell? Like `;` `&` `!` or space, quotes, etc.? You might have to quote the password.

But regardless, I recommend you do NOT put your passwords on the command-line. Anyone who can run `ps` on your server can therefore see your password in plain text.

Instead, put the user and password in an [options file](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html). That is, save a small file with the following content:

```
[mysqldump]
user = backupuser
password = ...
```

Of course write your own password where I put "...".

Change the permissions on the file so no one can read it except the user who runs your backups.

Then reference the options file when you run mysqldump:

```
mysqldump --defaults-file=myopts.cnf --all-databases ...
```

That way the password is not visible in the server's process list. Also there is no worry about special characters in your password.

P.S.: I'm not sure why you use `sudo` to run your backup. That should not be necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was using $ in password. Just removed that sign and it worked!

Comment: Thank you for suggesting option file solution. I am going to implement it.

Comment: I tried to use this option file solution in my shell script but it is giving me the following error:

mysqldump: [ERROR] unknown variable 'defaults-file=/home/username/bk/myopt.cnf'

Comment: I using this command in my shell script:
$MYSQLDUMP --force --opt --defaults-file=$OPT_FILE  --databases $db | gzip > "$BACKUP_DIR/mysql/$db.gz" 

Here $OPT_FILE is the variable

Comment: Anyway I fixed that error by placing --defaults-file argument in first place and --force --opt after that.

Comment: One more thing my backupuser is unable to backup sys database because it does not have enough permissions to backup sys database. Is sys database important to backup? Can I exclude it from backup?

Comment: You can exclude the `sys` database. In MySQL 5.7 and later, it will be installed by default on a new MySQL installation. There's no data in `sys`, just system views and procedures.